# How to open a file in its default program with python

Tags: python, windows, file, python-3.x, text

I want to open a file in python 3.5 in its default application, specifically 'screen.txt' in Notepad.

I have searched the internet, and found `os.startfile(path)` on most of the answers. I tried that with the file's path `os.startfile(C:\[directories n stuff]\screen.txt)` but it returned an error saying 'unexpected character after line continuation character'. I tried it without the file's path, just the file's name but it still didn't work.

What does this error mean? I have never seen it before.

Please provide a solution for opening a .txt file that works.

EDIT: I am on Windows 7 on a restricted (school) computer.

Comment: Did you write `os.startfile(C:\foo\bar\screen.txt)` or something like `os.startfile('C:\foo\bar\screen.txt')` with some quotes around the string?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan can you change os.startfile('C:\foo\bar\screen.txt') to os.startfile('C:\\foo\\bar\\screen.txt')

Comment: If you mean can I change it in my question here: nope, because I bet that if Adam put in the quotes he didn't put in the escapes. (See my answer, below.)

Comment: I didn't put in quotes or escape backslashes. Hmmmmm.  Thanks :))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's hard to be certain from your question as it stands, but I bet your problem is *backslashes*.

[EDITED to add:] Or actually maybe it's something simpler. Did you put quotes around your pathname at all? If not, that will certainly not work -- but once you do, you will find that then you need the rest of what I've written below.

In a Windows filesystem, the backslash `\` is the standard way to separate directories.

In a Python string literal, the backslash `\` is used for putting things into the string that would otherwise be difficult to enter. For instance, if you are writing a single-quoted string and you want a single quote in it, you can do this: `'don\'t'`. Or if you want a newline character, you can do this: `'First line.\nSecond line.'`

So if you take a Windows pathname and plug it into Python like this:

```
os.startfile('C:\foo\bar\baz')
```

then the string actually passed to `os.startfile` will not contain those backslashes; it will contain a form-feed character (from the `\f`) and two backspace characters (from the `\b`s), which is not what you want at all.

You can deal with this in three ways.

- You can use forward slashes instead of backslashes. Although Windows prefers backslashes in its user interface, forward slashes work too, and they don't have special meaning in Python string literals.
- You can "escape" the backslashes: two backslashes in a row mean an actual backslash. `os.startfile('C:\\foo\\bar\\baz')`
- You can use a "raw string literal". Put an `r` before the opening single or double quotes. This will make backslashes not get interpreted specially. `os.startfile(r'C:\foo\bar\baz')`

The last is maybe the nicest, *except* for one annoying quirk: backslash-quote is still special in a raw string literal so that you can still say `'don\'t'`, which means you can't *end* a raw string literal with a backslash.

Comment: Note that Windows uses only backslash as a path separator in its native object namespace (this is implemented internally and undocumented, e.g. drive letters and UNC paths are based on object symbolic links). Forward slash is translated to backslash in the NTDLL APIs that create native paths. However, several cases require backslash: naming a global kernel object (e.g. `Global\...`); registry paths, which translate to `\REGISTRY\MACHINE\...` or `\REGISTRY\USER\...`;  and filesystem paths that use the ``\\?\`` prefix to exceed `MAX_PATH` (260) characters.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. Also the `\\.\` that you sometimes need for accessing devices.

Comment: The local device prefix ``\\.`` works with slash (e.g. `os.listdir('//./pipe')`). Windows translates it to the DOS devices directory ``\??``. The ``\\?`` prefix is also mapped to ``\??``, and most APIs accept it instead of ``\\.``. The DOS devices directory is virtual. The object manager first checks the user's logon session directory, `\Sessions\0\DosDevices\[LOGON_ID]`, and then checks the global DOS devices directory `\GLOBAL??`. These directories have symbolic links to devices that are usually in `\Device`, e.g. `C:` => `\Device\HarddiskVolume1`.

Comment: I never knew you could do `//./` instead of ```\\.\```. Thank you!

Comment: I personally prefer using raw strings on Windows: `os.startfile(r'C:\foo\bar\baz')`. Note the `r` at the beginning of the string.

Comment: (That was the third of the "three ways" in my answer.)

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to open a file with the default program is `os.startfile`. You can do something a bit more manual using `os.system` or `subprocess` though:

```
os.system(r'start ' + path_to_file')
```

or

```
subprocess.Popen('{start} {path}'.format(
    start='start', path=path_to_file), shell=True)
```

Of course, this won't work cross-platform, but it might be enough for your use case.

Comment: You forgot `shell=True` for the subprocess example, and you should always use a command-line string in this case. `start` is an internal command of cmd.exe. There's no start.exe.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!

Comment: You're still using a list. `subprocess.list2cmdline` doesn't know how to build a command-line string for cmd.exe. Probably no one knows how to do this in general. I think it requires an AI beyond human comprehension. We can thwart Skynet by tricking it into running  cmd.exe.

Comment: Whoops. My bad. I fixed it again.

Comment: `shell=True` is implemented like this: `comspec = os.environ.get("COMSPEC", "cmd.exe");` `args = '{} /c "{}"'.format (comspec, args)`. So remove the `cmd` part. Modify `os.environ['COMSPEC']` to use a different shell. If only Microsoft would use a different shell. PowerShell is too non-traditional, and cmd.exe is antiquated, limited by its DOS & OS/2 roots, and buggy.

Comment: Well I learned something new today. I have often wondered how `shell=True` worked and now I know

Answer (score 0):

For example I created file `"test file.txt"` on my drive D: so file path is `'D:/test file.txt'`
Now I can open it with associated program with that script:

```
import os
os.startfile('d:/test file.txt')
```

Comment: I wondoer, why the message...
`AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'startfile'`