# Is there a way I can display data in Excel without saving a file first?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl to create a workbook in memory and fill it with data. Is there anyway to display that data in Excel at the end of the Python script without saving the file? It would be left up to the user to decide if they want to save the file or not. I'm guessing it's not possible but I wanted to see if I could get a more definitive answer here. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, but why not create the file, open it in Windows with Python ([something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37389854/4650297)), then in Python ask if the user wants to save the file. If "Yes", then just exit. If "No", then use python to delete the file from the system.

Comment: @BruceWayne Let's say the user does not want to save the file, but they want to look at it for the next 2 hours. Would the program be able to delete the temporary file while they still have it open?

Comment: Just curious, why don't you want to save first? This may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  If you're using a temporary file, it's still saved *somewhere*.  With a temporary file even if the user doesn't save, it'll be saved somewhere.  What saving the document does is "guarantee" if the user is prompted "Do you want to save the file or delete" and they choose "delete", you can easily remove the file from the system.  And if they're using a file for two+ hours, I'd recommend having it saved somewhere known, instead of temporary.

Comment: @BruceWayne Fair point. I hadn't heard of an XY problem before, but that sounds like what this is. I guess the only reason not to save would be to avoid file clutter. I was using this to display the contents of a database table in Excel. There are probably a lot of better ways to solve the problem then what I'm doing, but I don't have any real experience to lean on. I'm just trying to solve the problems that I run into the best I can.

Comment: For sure, that makes sense!  But (IMO) if you're wanting the user to view some database information, it may actually be better to save it first, let them use it as they please, then prompt them "Do you want to keep the file, or remove it" at some point later.  (Can Python see if a specific workbook is open in Excel? If so, maybe do a loop that checks if your file is open, and if so keep checking...if it's found *not* to be open, then you can prompt the user if they want to keep the file? Just a thought)

Comment: @BruceWayne I may have found a solution to the problem as posed originally (although this may not be the approach I should be using). I found a module called xlwings that seems to accomplish this. I can use it to open a new workbook and then add the data to it. At the end of the program it can activate the workbook and have it steal focus. I'll try implementing it and see what happens.

Comment: you can get help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74419712/creating-a-temporary-excel-file-using-openpyxl-python/74427140#74427140)